# Azure Http Trigger function Hangup socket after the first webhook response

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, http, azure-functions

I am using following code inside azure http trigger function.

```
var form = new FormData();
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
var https = require('https');
var httpAgents_ = new https.Agent({keepAlive: true});
httpAgents_.maxSockets = 200;
```

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

   let form_ = getMultiData(context);

   const response = await getResponse(form_,context);

    context.res = { 
           body: response };
    context.done;
};
```

```
async function cerenceLookResponse(body_,context)
{
  context.log('calling http function')
   const url = "https://webhook.site/5c7950af-85fc-49b5-a677-12430805a159";
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Connection":"Keep-Alive",
            "Content-Length":1330,
            "Keep-Alive": "timeout=30000",
            "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        },
        agent: httpAgents_
        
        }).then(res => res.text());
};
```

```
function getMultiData(context){
    var content = { "cmdDict":{ "device": "iso", };
    var content2 ={"appserver_data": {"action_mode": "default",  },"enable_filtering": 1,  };
    var options = { header: {'content-type': "application/JSON; charset=utf-8"}};

    form.append('RequestData', JSON.stringify(content), options);
    form.append('DictParameter', JSON.stringify(content2), options);

    var ar = []
    for(var i=0;i<54;i++){
        ar.push(form._streams[3][i]); }
    var ar2 = []
    for(var i=0;i<52;i++){
        ar2.push(form._streams[3][i]);}
    boun = ar2.join("")
    test1_orig = ar.join("")
    test2 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"DictParameter\"; paramName=\"REQUEST_INFO\""
    test1 = test1_orig + test2 + "\r\n" +'content-type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8\r\n' + '\r\n',
    form._streams[3] = test1
    form._streams.push(boun + "--\r\n");
  
    return form;

};
```

This program perfectly fine when I work with a local WebStorm terminal. However, on Azure portal first time it gets the response from the web hook and then if I want to run once again right after I get the response. The function stall and after 3 min and throws an error "socket hang upStack: FetchError". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is in the `getResponse` function? Also, why are you creating `form` variable in the global scope and not locally in `getMultiData` function?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `form` in the global scope. So every time you are calling the `getMultiData` function, duplicate stuffs getting added in the same `FormData` instance. Declare it locally inside `getMultiData` function.

Comment: I have a question, if we declare a global variable in Azure function will it be reinitialize every time a http request call the function or it will be there as long as we clean the memory or restart the function ?

Comment: Azure Function would manage the instance creation. Hence it can reuse old instance at times when invoked.